# Read millions of files with MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I use MultiResourceItemReader as reader in a job. However the resource (/opt/data/**/*.xml) has over a million files. Has anyone used MultiResourceItemReader to read very large number of files? The challenges are that it reads ALL the resources up front and it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to postpone it? I tried lazy-init and it doesn't seem to work.

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources"
        value="file:/opt/data/**/*.xml" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="itemReader" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hope you've combined MultiresouceItemReader with Paritioning to execute file reading task in each slave task in parallel.

Comment: Yes I have partition and thread pool executor to read/process/write the files. My question is when you start the job, during spring container and bean initialization, it "eagerly" sets resources by searching the designated folder using the matching pattern. It takes hours in my case (over a million files). It happens before executing read/process/write. And it happens every time you restart the job because of spring container and bean initialization. Is there a way to overcome that?